# How can infer a type based on a key from an array of typed objects?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript4.0

I'm trying to create a type based on an array of objects using one of the recurring (and required) keys, but typescript doesn't handle `Array.map()` the way I expect:

```
const list = [
  {
    _id: 'foo1'
  },
  { _id: 'foo2' }
] as const

const listIds = list.map(listValue => listValue._id)
```

I  expect `listIds` to be inferred as `['foo1', 'foo2']` but is instead treated as `("foo1" | "foo2")[]`. This doesn't make sense to me since it's impossible for `Array.map` to return an array of a different size than the original array.

Is there another way to get the results I'm looking for?

PS. See TypeScript Playground sample [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gKBjA3tnGAfQQBMAuGAcgDMQQBGKggXwBoDcYCcSLq6IAExVuhGC0wBdGAEMIMUJCiZMUAJ4AHAKYwAMkigBJKNoC2qGBp0ga8Q%20gDW29batbtbxNCmqlyb2NSBTRAgDozWU0ACkCANVk4AFddFAA%20e2gE5O0wvgBKTAB6IpgAUQAPHWBYQKNgqxAYACNdBDAabQAnLu1SOQV0WnomNgF6ERlmpNgkGHbobVl%206IAiQQZVmAAfGHWJ1fz0KSA).

Comment: Usualy you do it with overloading. See this https://tsplay.dev/WJRxkW . Here https://catchts.com/tuples you can find some explanation. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case of getting the value of a specific key, a helper function can be used:

```ts
const mapByKey = <A extends readonly unknown[], K extends keyof A[number]>(
  array: A,
  key: K
// the -readonly ensures the return type isn't readonly even if the
// input array is
): {-readonly [P in keyof A]: A[P][K]} =>
  array.map((x: A[number]) => x[key]) as {-readonly [P in keyof A]: A[P][K]}

// ['foo1', 'foo2']
const listIds = mapByKey(list, '_id')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gKBjA3tnGAfQQBMAuGAcgDMQQBGKggXwBoDcYCcSLq6IAEzMcLTAF0YAQwgxQkKJkwLkAW2kAHAEIBPANIBTXahgAeAIIxDADyiGwpOQCdD00uDgmArmADWYCAA7mDoEmww+tZ2Dk4wfsYgNDAW6GDeagBGhs4SAHwAFATSzs7SupQWHDgJFZGYAJSUuAC0ru6eJugACjAIYPGJyRYSlT0S6PoSLKh5xaXlAHQamgUFNmPpWTkSDbMwNui1uzJyre0eYF4Yvf2Dukkpoynjk9PKAPQfGLT0TBG-YRUCQqcDIRDQACScTQKz0Rl0BQhUABfCoDUwQA)

---

However, I don't think there's a simple way of generalising this for any kind of function.

What we really want:

```ts
declare const map: <A extends readonly unknown[], F>(
  array: A,
  fn: <T extends A[number]>(x: T) => F<T>
): {-readonly [K in keyof A]: F<A[K]>}
// with your example F would be like a generic type like
// type F<T> = T['_id']
```

However, this doesn't compile as [TypeScript lacks higher-kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213). There are various hacks for emulating this in TypeScript, but they're cumbersome to use and I don't personally think it's worth it for this problem.